# Upgraded to Rails 6.1 and DartSass - now no JS assets are found

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I recently upgraded to Dartsass: `gem "dartsass-rails", "~> 0.4.0"`.  Now my Javascript assets are broken... Specifically:

```
application-2780ff1b190fd971bdc5.js:1  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
popper-af263f978197970b01a7.js:1  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

application.html still has pack and link tags:

```
 <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```